# collision is not happening after freezing

Tags: unity-game-engine

i am going to build brick braker game. here when i have freeze the rotation in y and x axis of the pad.then the colloision of the ball and the pad is not working. the ball is going through the pad? why this is happen? i have added rigid2D and the  collider for the both object. here is my script.

```
 using System.Collections; 
     using System.Collections.Generic;
      usingUnityEngine; 
      public class PaddleScript : MonoBehaviour {


     public Rigidbody2D rb;  
      public float speed;
      public float maxX;

    `

    // Use this for initialization

    void Start () {

        }
        // Update is called once per frame
            void Update () {
            float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            if (x==0){
                Stop();
            }
            if (x<0){
                MoveLeft();
            }
            if (x>0){
                MoveRight();
            }
            Vector3 pos=transform.position;
            pos.x = Mathf.Clamp(pos.x,-maxX,maxX); //limit the boundary
            transform.position=pos;
     }

     `void MoveLeft(){ rb.velocity= new Vector2 (-speed,0); }` 


         void MoveRight() { rb.velocity= new Vector2 (speed,0); } 



         void Stop(){ rb.velocity= Vector 2.zero; } }

    `
```

Comment: Could you check if the z transform of each object is different? In case of 2D they have to be on the same depth. You can also look at the size of your colliders and whether they have kinematic on some how.

Comment: can you share your speed variable for us. It can be the problem sometimes

Comment: speed varriable is 5@Prodian

Comment: size of box collider is X:1.04 ,Y 0.24 and size of the circle collider is Radious:0.03114287 X:-0.000668425 Y:-0.001168945. @artofshashank

Comment: Can you display the properties of your pad and your ball? Just a screenshot